# json-server can't add autogenerated request body attributes in POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-server

I am using json-server library in my nodejs project to start a mocked server and perform POST operations. My request body doesn't have id, userId, and customerGuid which are all autogenerated fields. I tried to do this below but it only adds id and never adds userId and customerGuid.

Request body used for POST:

```
{
    "name": "Leon"
    "qty": 3
}
```

Response body received for POST above is:

```
{
    "name": "Leon",
    "qty": 3,
    "id": 2
}
```

Expected POST response body which i can't figure out why userId and customerGuid can't be added:

```
{
    "name": "Leon",
    "qty": 3,
    "id" : 2,
    "userId": 37,
    "customerGuid": "af9a012b-faf2-4ef5-ae0c-51f945adff6c"
}
```

Code in data.js:

```
const faker = require('faker')

let data = {
    user : []
}

data.user.push({
    id: faker.random.number({min:25,max:50}),     
    userId: faker.random.number({min:25,max:50}),
    customerGuid: faker.random.uuid(), 
    name: faker.company.companyName(),
    qty: faker.address.city()
})


module.exports = data
```

Comment: isn't POST supposed to update the database? what did you expect as a return value?